# Is there any dynamic symbolic execution tool for smart contract

Tags: solidity, security

There is a question ([Security analysis tool for Ethereum smart contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31519/security-analysis-tool-for-ethereum-smart-contracts)) similar to me, but it presents mostly static analysis tools. I'd like to know if there is any better dynamical analysis tool suitable my application. 
Concretely, i wonder if there is any tool can be used to generate  path constrains  from entry point to exploit point and the exploit point is known. Or is there any  open project worth learning?
Please give some suggestions, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! This is likely a duplicate.

Comment: Have you checked Oyente, Manticore, Mythril Classic?

Comment: @Honor LT I have explored Oyente, it's a static analysis tool